# Custom properties for ProjectItems in a Flavored Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsx

Is it possible to have custom properties for Project items while implementing a flavored C# project? For example add a MyProperty property to a class.cs's Properties Window.

Thanks in adavance.

Kenny

Answer (score 1):

I got this question answered on the VSX forums heres the [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/431fbf37-4d6f-469c-a261-c3205c27dc88?prof=required&lc=1033) if anyone else gets stuck on this kind of thing.

Kenny